# Unity Setting parents gameObjects transform into the childs transform variables?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a good way to do this, i have copied my code below. This is my code so that the gameObjects patrol around a certain area of a map, i need a way so that when the enemies are spawned in to set the transform relative to the gameObject spawning the enemy in.

When I spawn my enemy in from the prefab, the enemy should patrol around the spawn point which spawned it in, however i have multiple points within the game which spawns the enemies in. The Patrol script has a transform `public Transform moveSpots;` which i assign the spawn point objects to.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Patrol0 : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed;
    public Transform moveSpots;
    private float waitTime;
    public float StartwaitTime;
    public float MinX;
    public float MaxX;
    public float MinY;
    public float MaxY;
    void start()
    {
        moveSpots = GetComponentInParent<Transform>();
        waitTime = StartwaitTime;
        moveSpots.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(MinX, MaxX), Random.Range(MinY, MaxX));
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, moveSpots.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
        if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, moveSpots.position) < 0.2f)
        {
            if (waitTime <= 0)
            {
                moveSpots.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(MinX, MaxX), Random.Range(MinY, MaxX));
                waitTime = StartwaitTime;
            }
            else
            {
                waitTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam. Welcome to Stackoverflow! It would be easier for us if you add your code to your question not the screenshot though.

Comment: Can you explain more about what you have and what do you want to get?

Comment: *gameObject.transform.parent* will give you the parent transform for a child component.

Comment: You mean like `parentObject.transform.SetParent(childObject.transform);`?

Comment: It would be great if you add your code .. as text though

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the object being spawned is also getting parented to the thing that is spawning, you could just replace all of your `transform.position` references with `transform.localPosition`. If not you can use [Transform.TransformPoint()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.TransformPoint.html) called from the spawner's transform.

```
Transform Spawner;

void start()
{
    moveSpots = GetComponentInParent<Transform>();
    waitTime = StartwaitTime;
    moveSpots.position = new Vector2(Random.Range(MinX, MaxX), Random.Range(MinY, MaxX));
    moveSpots.position = Spawner.TransformPoint(moveSpots.position);
}
```

This will take the local space `moveSpots.position` and convert it to world space relative to the `Spawner`.